# convert int color to int components

Tags: java, colors

I obtain pixel color by

```
int color = image.getRGB(x,y);
```

then i want to acquire red, green, blue components separately. How to do that? Maybe using some bitmask?

```
int green = color&0x00ff00;
```

apparently not working... :(

Answer (score 31):

To get color components you can use:

```
import android.graphics.Color;

        int r = Color.red(intColor);
        int g = Color.green(intColor);
        int b = Color.blue(intColor);
        int a = Color.alpha(intColor);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int value = image.getRGB(x,y);
R = (byte)(value & 0x000000FF);
G = (byte)((value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
B = (byte)((value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
A = (byte)((value & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
```

May need to flip the R, A, or B around.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to shift the byte to the right:

```
int green = (color & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
```

Comment: one more thing. Is 0x00ff equal 0x00ff00 ?

Comment: As the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) says, `getRGB` return rgba, and not rgb...

Comment: 0x00ff is 0xff but 0xff00 is not, as 001 is the same as one (1), but not the same as one hundred!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Color` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29) and pass the given integer and `hasalpha=true`:

```
Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x,y), true);
```

[getRGB](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29) returns the color of type [TYPE_INT_ARGB](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB) which means it has an alpha channel.

Comment: So can't we somehow ignore alpha? and make logic AND and shift?

Comment: I think you can. Just read the javadocs to make sure you know the correct byte order of rgb: (red, green, blue, alpha) or (alpha red green blue). And then do as codymanix suggested. I'm not sure that and/shift logic will be cross-architecture in this case, however.